# Moved nav html code to separate file, javascript not working now

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, null, nav

> My navbar was fully working with the hamburger icon to animate out
> using the javascript file until I decided to move the nav code to a
> separate file so I could load it to all different html documents. Now
> when I try to click on the burger icon I receive the error below. The
> code still loads the nav bar (logo, icon, formatting) except the
> javascript doesn't work because it says the value of getElementById is
> null. Don't know how to fix it.

[IMAGE OF CURRENT ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt0YT.jpg)
[**FOLDER WITH TEXT FILES OF ALL THE CODE**](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1N06OxzBNpcbRXerYnW4dZvejLiL64xwK?usp=sharing)

Comment: It would be helpful if you can attach the code samples as the given information is not sufficient.

Comment: I added a folder with all the code if that helps!

Comment: Please read [ask]. Don't post pictures of code. Do (if possible) make use of the live demo feature of the question editor.

Answer (score -1):

Your code runs before the `.load()` function can return anything. It runs asynchronously to stop blocking other code from running. You can feed a callback function to the load function which will be called when the load function returns. Then the DOM will be updated to know your nav elements.
You can encapsulate your other code in a function and just put that function name as an argument or you can pass an anonymous function and just put all the stuff in there on the spot.

Example:

```
$('#nav-placeholder').load('assets/nav.html', function() {
    const ham = document.getElementById('ham');
    ham.addEventListener...
    ...
    ..
    .
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried to put all the code with in the example function you provided and I now receive "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null." Not sure if I implemented your solution incorrectly however the nav still does not function.

Comment: Without seeing any of your now updated code I can't say much. You can try and log 'this' inside your callback function. If everything worked as intended 'this' should be the #nav-placeholder element.
If you've got difficulties with the syntax you can check in the docs:
https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I attached a folder of all the current code in my original question above if that helps.

Comment: I don't know, sorry